# UPDATE table - 0 rows affected

Tags: mysql, mariadb, mysql-workbench

I wrote an UPDATE command whose syntax is good, but it **doesn't affect any of the rows**, so it doesn't actually work. [1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MXinf.png

```
update T1 c, T2 dk
    set c.date = dk.dates, c.field = 'event_dt'  
where c.id = dk.id and c.age = dk.age and c.height = dk.height and c.country = dk.country
    and c.id is not null and c.date is null and c.age is not null and c.height is not null and c.country is not null;
```

how can I solve the problem?
thanks!

Comment: You will need to provide a dataset and show how it's not working. My guess is that the `WHERE` condition is too exclusive...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest writing this as an update join:

```sql
UPDATE T1 c
INNER JOIN T2 dk
    ON c.id = dk.id and c.age = dk.age and c.height = dk.height and c.country = dk.country
SET c.date = dk.dates, c.field = 'event_dt'  
WHERE c.id IS NOT NULL AND c.date IS NULL AND c.age IS NOT NULL AND
      c.height IS NOT NULL AND c.country IS NOT NULL;
```

If the above also does not update any rows, then either your data or your logic is off.